# Why do I need to work harder to make my Rails application fit into a RESTful architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rest

I started a Rails project recently and decided to use RESTful controllers. I created controllers for my key entities (such as Country) and added `index`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `show`, `update` and `delete`. I added my `map.resources :country` to my routes file and life was good.

After development progressed a little, I started to encounter problems. I sometimes needed extra actions in my controller. First there was the `search` action that returned the options for my fancy autocompleting search box. Then came the need to display the countries in two different ways in different places in the application (the data displayed was different too, so it wasn't just two views) - I added the `index_full` action. Then I wanted to show a country by name in the URL, not by id so I added the `show_by_name` action.

What do you do when you need actions beyond the standard `index`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `show`, `update`, `delete` in a RESTful controller in Rails? Do I need to add (and maintain) manual routes in the routes.rb file (which is a pain), do they go in a different controller, do I become unRESTful or am I missing something fundamental?

I guess I am asking, do I need to work harder and add actions into my routes.rb file for the privilege of being RESTful? If I wasn't using `map.resources` to add the REST goodies, the standard `:controller/:action, :controller/:action/:id` routes would handle pretty much everything automatically.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion about the meaning of REST due to rails default methods. REST is not limited to those methods, and really isn't about those particular methods at all. I also don't understand why you feel you have to work harder when adding additional methods to a controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I go beyond the standard CRUD actions with my models, I normally just add the methods as required. Searching is something I add to many controllers, but not every one, so I add it and maintain the routes normally:

```
map.resources :events, :collection => { :search => :get }
```

Moving these actions to an entirely separate controller might keep some of your controllers RESTful, but I find that keeping them in context is far more useful.

Comment: I just hate having to add and maintain lots action names in my routes file manually. If I wasn't using REST then I wouldn't need to do it. Is there a cleaner way? If not then this it is.

Comment: How would you not need to handle route edits otherwise?  By just using the ":controller => XXX, :action => YYY" syntax?  Named routes are a good practice, whether or not you're using REST.

Comment: Search, index_full, show_by_name are all parameterized retrieve actions (i.e. the R in CRUD). There's no need to add new routes.

Answer (score 13):

I would treat `search` as a special case of `index`. Both actions return a collection of resources. The request parameters should specify things like page, limit, sort order, and search query.

For example:

```
/resources/index # normal index
/resources/index?query=foo # search for 'foo'
```

And in resources_controller:

```
before_filter :do_some_preprocessing_on_parameters

def index
  @resources = Resource.find_by_param(@preprocessed_params)
end
```

As for `index_full` and `search_by_name`, you might look at splitting your current controller into two. There's a smell about what you've described.

Having said that, you're absolutely right that there's no point in forcing your app to user restful routes when it doesn't deliver anything over `/:controller/:action/:id`. To make the decision, look how frequently you're using the restful resource route helpers in forms and links. If you're not using them, I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: The approach you describe at the start breaks the MVC pattern in my mind. I go from having an action that does one thing cleanly to an action that does lots of different things in a hidden way. Your last point is interesting - maybe I shouldn't be using restful routes at all?

Comment: I see it this way: a search finds a bunch of resources and displays them in some kind of order. Index action does the same, but - by default - in a hardcoded way. So actually, index is a special case of search :)

Comment: I agree with EmbiggensTheMind: I see index as a special case of search.

Answer (score 5):

REST does not specify that you can't have additional views. No real world application is going to be able use only the supplied actions; this is why you can add your own actions.

REST is about being able to make stateless calls to the server. Your search action is stateless each time as the data so far is supplied back, correct? Your alternate display action is also stateless, just a different view.

As to if they should be manual routes or a new controller, that depends on how distinct the activity is. Your alternate view, if it provides a full set of CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations would do well to be in a new controller. If you only have an alternate *view* to the data, I would just add an alternate view action.

In other words, it doesn't sound like your application is failing to be RESTful, it is more an issue of realizing that the automatically generated feature set is a starting point, not a conclusion.

Comment: I am being stateful, so I'm using REST properly. I guess my concern is that bacause I've decided to be RESTful I now need to do lots more work in my routes.rb file which I wouldn't need to do if I didn't use REST.

Comment: Well, the code has to go somewhere: I'm curious if you are feeling that having clearly defined actions is less useful than having extra flag data that says which view to use? While the flag is easy to code, it obscures what the action is doing quite a bit. The discoverable nature of actions is good.

Comment: I'm 100% against the flag idea - no worries there. The problem is that once I add the map.resources line for the controller to add the REST mappings, my actions go from being automatically discoverable to needing to be manually configured in the routes file. I then start having Struts flashbacks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion they may have gone a bit off the rails here. What happened to DRY?

I'm just getting back into Rails not having done much development with it since beta and I'm still waiting for the light-bulb to come on here. I'm still giving it a chance but if it hasn't happened for me by the end of my current project I'll probably just drop-back to the old standard routes and define the methods as I actually need them for the next one.

Comment: Resource routes have little effect on DRYness, it's more about convention over configuration.  They set up standard named routes for all CRUD actions, which for the 20 or so Rails apps I've worked on have always been upwards of 90% of routes.  Of course using the default :controller/:action/:id seems terse, but how DRY is it when you have thousands upon thousands of url_for :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar', :id => @foo littered throughout your templates rather than foo_url(@foo)?

Answer (score 0):

I won't go on to explain more about REST since I think that has been answered in this question, however I will talk a little bit about the default route.

My main problem with the default route is that if you have multiple sites using the same Rails app it can look horrible.

For example there may be controllers that you don't want people to be able to see on one app:

```
http://example1.somesite.com/example_2/foo/bar/1
```

compare this to

```
/:controller/:action/:id
```

This would go to the controller example_2/foo, action bar and id 1

I consider this to be the main flaw of Rails' default route and this is something that RESTful routes (with subdomain extensions) or only named routes (`map.connect 'foo'` ... ) can fix.

Answer (score -1):

To remain RESTful in your design, you need to rethink what you call a resource.

In your example a show action for a search controller, (search resource) is the direction to remain restful.

In mine, I have a dashboard controller (show) and controllers for single fields of in-place ecditors (show and update)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Could you be more specific?  Are you saying that some actions (such as searching) should be seen as resources?  Something like "map.resources :user_search"?