# rails routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have some RESTful controllers and have added a custom method to `application_controller`.
I have not changed anything in the routes to indicate this new method. The method is `poll_memos`. I have entered the following URL:

> /groups/1234/poll_memos

I get the following error:

> Unknown action
>
> No action responded to 1234. Actions: create, destroy, edit, index, new, poll_memos, show, and update

Two questions: Since I didn't modify routes how does rails know about `poll_memos`? Second, since it seems to know about it, why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thats a restful route that rails automatically generates. This means you'll need to add it yourself.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230335/491609#491609) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401241/adding-an-action-to-an-existing-controller-ruby-on-rails).

And its in the actions because its in the controller, the error message is just printing all actions.

Answer (score 1):

The correct url is /groups/poll_memos/1234.  In your example rails thinks that you're trying to call controller method named "1234", which is absent, of course.

Rails knows about poll_memos because the code that prints the error message looks at controller code, not to the routing.  You may set routes up in such a way that it will say that there is poll_memos method, but you're unable to access it via URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are most likely triggering the default route:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

Your URL

```
/groups/1234/poll_memos
```

would map as follows:

```
{:controller => "groups", :action => "1234", :id => "poll_memos"}
```

Also, as you are using a restful style you need to configure the route.  To get the poll memos working on the items in the collection you'll need to modify your routes to map as follows:

```
map.resources :groups, :member => {:poll_memos => :get}
```